# How do I launch a non-modal dialog in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a C# application designed using MVVM. The structure is conventional.

I have a view model where I would like to launch a custom non-modal dialog.

This dialog is responsible for collecting a data bound serial number.

Here is how I imagine my non-modal dialog:

[image]

Here is the Xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="RailComm.EmbeddedApplications.EacManagementTool.Views.RestoreDeviceDialogView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RailComm.EmbeddedApplications.EacManagementTool.Views"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        Title="Device Restore" Height="150" Width="375">
        <Window.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="SelectableLabel">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1">This device has no identity, would you like to restore it?</Label>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="2" >
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right">Device IP:</Label>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding IpAddress, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource SelectableLabel}"></TextBox>
                </UniformGrid>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
                <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="2" >
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right">Serial Number:</Label>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding SerialNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                </UniformGrid>
            </StackPanel>
            <DockPanel Grid.Row="3">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Margin="5">
                    <Button Content="No" Command="{Binding CancelCommand }" Width="45"/>
                    <Separator Width="5"/>
                    <Button Content="Identify" Command="{Binding IdentifyCommand }"/>
                    <Separator/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Now I would like to hook this into my existing view model, which also contains other view models as properties.

The view model I'd like to add this too, has a method called `GetUpdate()`. At a certain point in the method I'd like to display the non-modal dialog to the user. If the serial number passes a check I'll except the result and close the dialog. If the serial number fails I'd like to display an error in the same dialog.

I plan on having these files:

```
ExistingViewModel.cs
DialogViewModel.cs
DialogView.xaml
```

I just don't know how to hook them up. Displaying this model asynchronously is very important to me. I would likely run the dialog in a `Task.Rush()`..

This dialog does not update the parent view. This dialog just get the value to pass to another method.

How can I implement this? I've seen other peoples approaches but they don't make sense for my implementation. They don't show/explain how the view and the view models are connected. They often leave things out or chunks of code that don't have a home, e.g. this code should go into this class...

Major thanks to anyone who can get me on the right track with this!

Comment: Task.Rush() is probably Run(). You can't/shouldn't do that.  UI elements need to exist in single threaded apartments, or STA threads.  In particular, they need a message pump in the thread in order to process input from the user.  Running UI in a different thread is bad juju, and a sign that your design is completely off the rails.  I don't understand why you want a "non-modal" dialog, so I can't advise further.  Other than, don't do that.  Don't do any of that.  No. Stop.

Comment: You can create a pop-up or another user control that takes a space on Mainwindow when it is shown.

Comment: I usually use my own custom Popup `UserControl` for something like this... can find the code [here](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) if you're interested. Its probably the sort of solution I would use here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it as an example.
Showing Dialogs When Using the MVVM Pattern 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36745/Showing-Dialogs-When-Using-the-MVVM-Pattern

Important is to keep your `ViewModel` clean with view related stuff. Use an `IDialogService` with abstracts the view stuff away and could be injected in the `ViewModel` and easy mocked for testing.

DialogService would also be a good key word in combination with MVVM there a tons of examples.
This gives you also full control on the behavior of your dialog.

HTH